# How do I insert data of a for loop in a specific index?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have a "for" loop that is creating a variable each time through the loop.  I am attempting to insert the results into an empty array at the index of the "i" in the loop.  From the best I can tell it seems I need to create a ArrayList vs. an Array to make this happen.

```
int varNum = 10;  
Array someArr = new Array ();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
varNum = varNum +i;
someArr[i] = varNum;
}
```

On the first loop I want the 10 to be inserted in my array at the "0 index", 11 inserted at "1 index", 12 at the "2 Index".

**The important part is that the Array is not a set size, because I do not know how many indexes I will need in the array, so I want to add them as I needed.

Comment: Please elaborate what you have already tried and where you are struggeling to solve the issue with your own recommendation to use `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an ArrayList you can call add like this:

```
int varNum = 10;
ArrayList<Integer> someArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    varNum = varNum + i;
    someArr.add(varNum);
}
```

This will allow you to dynamically fill the ArrayList dependent upon how many values it needs to hold.

Answer (score 0):

Better use an ArrayList then, and use their .add() method

```
someArr.add(varNum)
```